# Run Hive and Hadoop batch file on HDInsight

Tags: windows, hadoop, command-line, hive, azure-hdinsight

I'm having a bit of problem getting HDInsight working via Powershell. As a temporary work around can anyone point me in the right direction of running Hive/Hadoop scripts via a bat file.

I tried creating a bat file and changing it to the hive bin folder and run some commands but it didn't work. I'm guessing that's opening the dos prompt and running commands rather than the hadoop commandline.

Cheers, Chris.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use the hive commmand line in a .bat file running on the cluster head node. To do this you would have to enable Remote Desktop in the Azure control panel, and then RDP in to the head node.

You can then run a .bat file containing something like

```
%Hive_Home%\bin\hive -e "your query here"
```

of if you have a longer query it might make sense to put that in a separate file and use:

```
%Hive_Home%\bin\hive -f "your query here"
```

While this is *possible*, it's certainly not *advisable*. I would strongly recommend not enabling the Remote Desktop connection on your cluster and instead using the PowerShell `Invoke-Hive` command from the client which is doing the scheduling. Of course you can wrap execution of that PowerShell in a bat file if you really have to, but you're not really gaining anything at that point. If your goal is to schedule a hive query to run, you're probably better just scheduling a PowerShell script.

Comment: Can I just add that I have run into a limitation where jobs submitted from Powershell seemingly fail after one hour with error "The requested task failed to complete in the allotted time (01:00:00)." even tho the job actually has not failed, it is still running. For this reason I sometimes prefer to run Hive jobs via the command-line on the head node.

Comment: @jamiet, invoke-hive has a timeout you can't change.  If you want to issue a longer running query use New-AzureHDInsightHiveJobDefinition/Start-AzureHDInsightJob

Answer (score 0):

You can use Invoke-Hive -File .  For more information, see http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/using-hive-with-hdinsight/.

If you want to use the Hive command line, you must rdp into the cluster head node. From the Hadoop command line, run the following commands:

cd %Hive_Home%\bin
Hive

Comment: I can't use powershell at the moment. How do I run Hive from a file like a bat file in Windows. I want to run a script on a timer.